# Salesforce 1 SSO Issue community

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I want to directly access one community from another community when I am logged in in the salesforce 1 mobile app.Currently everytime when I try to switch from one community to another it always ask for other community password in salesforce 1.It looks like SAML needs to be configured.Do you have any steps by which I don't need to enter password and directly move from one community from another community